# Question about spectrum emissions

Tags: atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, wavelength

I was studying about spectrum emissions but I have a question.

For example if I have $2$ electrons from different atoms with different distances from the nucleus, then I  hit them with fire  causing the excitation of  both electrons, after this each electron generate a series of spectral lines. What factors depend on whether these lines are in an area of ​​greater or lesser wavelength?

Answer (score 0):

> For example if I have "2 electrons from different atoms" with different distances from the nucleus,

In the microscopic level of atoms and electrons which is modelled with quantum (not classical) mechanics, you cannot have "2 electrons from different atoms". The electrons you can have if they are free of an atom, otherwise you have "two atoms with electrons bound at different energy levels in each atom" . The different energy levels have on the average a [different  distance](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) from the nucleus.

> then I hit them with fire causing the excitation of both electrons,

Photons from the fire can have enough energy to excite the atoms further, take the electrons to higher energy levels.

> after this each electron generate a series of spectral lines "falling to the ground state of the atomic levels".

> What factors depend on whether these lines are in an area of ​​greater or lesser wavelength?

The quantum mechanical solutions for the atoms gives the energy levels, [see this for hydrogen.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html).

The possible wavelengths in the de-excitations will be the energy differences between the energy levels, and they will be within the range of the photon energies that excited the atom to higher energy levels.